# Adding data=writeback to a ext4 fstab entry, results in read-only filesystem

Tags: fstab

I have this fstab entry :

`LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,noatime,nobarrier,data=writeback,rw    0 0`

I added rw to see if would fix my issue but it wont. After boot I get a read-only file system that I can't fix either using common results found on google.

Useful output. There are no errors with `dmesg | grep error`

```
root@w2:~# dmesg | grep EXT4
[    8.372564] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:                                                                                                                      (null)
[    8.892244] EXT4-fs (sda1): Cannot change data mode on remount
```

Comment: Have you mount the rootfs with exactly the same parameters in initrd phase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setting it late in the fstab, why not use `tune2fs` to make it the default for that filesystem:

```
tune2fs -o journal_data_writeback /dev/sdXY
```

Do this once then reboot.

Comment: Good point!  My instinct would be to set `rootflags=` on the kernel command line, but `tune2fs` seems like a more reliable way to work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks. It did work, is this safe? And it's permanent too? How can I check if worked?

Comment: tune2fs is not a "hack", if that is what you are worried about. It is permanent, though you can still override these *defaults* by an explicit mount option. You can see the result with `tune2fs -l` which will list it as `Default mount options:    journal_data_writeback ...`. And of course after the mount you can use `findmnt /dev/sdXY` to list the mount options in use where you should see `data=writeback`.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to remount the filesystem read-write, try this command

```
mount LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / -oremount,rw
```

Explanation: when you pass both the device and the mount point to `mount`, it doesn't read options from `/etc/fstab`.  But when you only pass one or the other, it will read the `data=writeback` option from /etc/fstab.

Then you can edit `/etc/fstab` back, to regain permanent read-write access to your system.